# how come class methods don't behave normally with react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Given a component like this :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {}

  sayHello() {
    // 'this' is undefined here... It should point to the component instance
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.sayHello}>
        clickMe
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

how come sayHello can't access `this` ? That is not the expected behavior of an ES6 class.
What am I missing out on ?

Comment: You are missing binding `sayHello` method to App class.

Comment: how come you don't run into that problem with angular ?

Comment: I don't have experience with angular so cant say about that. But this is more of javascript concept.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript `this` depends on how you call the method. This can be changed by binding `this` inside a method. To illustrate what is happening in your example:

```
class App {
    sayHello() {
        console.log(this)
    }
}

const a = new App()
a.sayHello() // A {}
const callback = a.sayHello // what you are passing as a callback to onClick
callback() // undefined
```

To fix this problem you need to bind `this` in `sayHello` function. You can use class properties to achieve this. This is still an experimental feature of javascript but seems to be a community accepted way of binding `this` for React components.

```
class App {
    sayHello = () => {
        console.log(this)
    }
}

callback() // A {}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`div` it self is another Class** so when calls your `sayHello` inside himself it will change `this`.

All you have to do is bind this to sayHello or call it via ES6 arrow function.

```
<div onClick={ this.sayHello.bind(this) }>
```

or

```
<div onClick={ (event) => this.sayHello(event) }>
```

Comment: I don’t think this is true. A function that isn’t bound and is called not on an object will have ‘this’ be the global scope.